# Value of int on Arduino not changing

Tags: arduino

I have my code set up so that when I push a certain button, specific values get added to: int finalVal = 0; but when I look at the Seral Monitor, it says that finalVal at 0. My goal is to create a sort of password-like system where if you push the right buttons in the right order then a button will light up.

My code:

```
const int button1 = 2;
const int button2 = 3;
const int button3 = 4;
const int led = 13;

int button1Val = 5.43678;
int button2Val = 1.287953156;
int button3Val = 3.141592;
int finalVal = 0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println(finalVal);

  int button1St, button2St, button3St;

  button1St = digitalRead(button1);
  button2St = digitalRead(button2);
  button3St = digitalRead(button3);

  if ((button1St == LOW))
    {
        finalVal + button1Val;
    }
  else
    {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(300);
    }



  if ((button1St == LOW))
    {
        finalVal + button2Val;
    }
  else
    {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(300);
    }



  if ((button1St == LOW))
    {
        finalVal + button3Val;
    }
  else
    {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
        delay(300);
    }



    if ((finalVal == 25.169430312))
      {
          digitalWrite(led, LOW);
      }
    else
      {
          digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
          delay(300);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating your `finalVal` variable.

your `finalVal + buttonxVal` doesn't do what you want, you are probably looking for `finalVal += buttonxVal`.

```
if ((button1St == LOW))
{
        finalVal + button3Val;
}
```

For other tests you need to change `button1St` to `button2St` and `button3St`

And `int` stands for Integer, you are storing float values in integers.

Answer (score 0):

`finalVal + button1Val;` does not actually change the value of the `finalVal` variable.

You must assign a new value to `finalVal` by using an `=` sign.

In your case, you would do:

```
finalVal = finalVal + button1Val;
```

When just adding an additional value to an original variable value, you can use the following shortcut, which is in essence the same as the above line of code:

```
finalVal += button1Val;
```

You will need to implement this fix for all 3 of your buttons.